# How to send auto push notifications to a particular user when a new record is added in the database in Parse?

Tags: android, parsing, push-notification

I'm able to send push notifications using the console in parse.com, but I need auto pushes when a new record is added in the database.

Should I use background jobs or is there any simpler way?

Can someone suggest a good way to achieve this?

Comment: cloud code you have to do for it . i am also trying that now .